# How to make area outside of custom dialog view unclickable?

Tags: android, dialog, android-custom-view

I created a custom dialog (no, this is not dialog object) from an image and some other views. The conflict I am having with this custom dialog (again, this is a layout) is that the area around it closes the custom dialog. Is there a way I can make the outside area unclickable?

I have tried wrapping the dialog view with a fullscreen frameLayout w/ transparent background, and then programmatically I set the frame attribute to setClickable(false).

```
framelayout.setClickable(false);
```

This does nothing. It still closes the dialog. Any other suggestions? Thank you in advance.

This is my code:

```
//used to disable background from closing the custom dialog
private FrameLayout fl; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.layout_dialog);

btnContinue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnContinue);
btnContinue.setOnClickListener(this);

fl.setClickable(false); //background suppose to lock

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.btnContinue:
finish();
}
break;  
}
}
```

I also have another class for broadcastReceiver

```
public class DialogManagerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(IdeaPlayInterfaceApplication.isActivityVisible()){
             Intent i=new Intent(context,CustomDialogActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is that this custom dialog is not called at a specific instance, it is called every set amount of time no matter what I am doing in the application.

I use an Intent and PendingIntent to repeatedly call this custom dialog over time. With something like this:

```
cancelAlarmNotificationMonitoring(context);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis()+ALARM_INTERVAL,ALARM_INTERVAL, pintent);
```

EDIT: As per your request, here is the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/bkg_img"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bg1"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/img_icon"
                android:padding="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:text="@string/text"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="35sp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnContinue"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_btn"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="@string/btn_continue_no_arrow"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_18"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hopefully this is more clear now.

Answer (score 5):

You can configure this using your dialog object and setting its `setCanceledOnTouchOutside` to false to disable the dialog to dialog to be canceled upon click outside its boundaries.

**sample:**

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false); // will disable dialog outside touch
```

Comment: I am not using a dialog. I created a service, and in an Activity I setContentView to a layout that is my custom dialog. Is there any equivalent function for layouts?

Comment: @portfoliobuilder then how is that cancelled when it is an activity??

Comment: Look at my update, this should be clear now. I am not using dialog object. I am just calling a class with a layout, and now I am wondering if there is a way of disabling the touch of the outside of this. Similar to how dialogs work with setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

Comment: @portfoliobuilder can you post the `layout_dialog`

Answer (score 0):

`Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context); 
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
 dialog.setCancelable(false);`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out answer. I set onClickListener to the FrameLayout and then did nothing. Works fine. Thank you!